# Expand TH Element on Row Hover

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a table that highlights the row and column when a cell is hovered.

This is a fiddle of it in action:
https://jsfiddle.net/cbsuwz5y/4/

The jquery controlling the dom is here:

```
$("table").on('mouseover mousedown mouseleave', 'td', function (e) {
                    if (e.type == 'mouseover' || e.type == 'mousedown') {
                        $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
                        $(this).closest('table').find("col").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");
                    } else {
                        $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
                        $(this).closest('table').find('col').eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");

                    }
                });
```

What I want, is when the cell is hovered, the TH element expands. I am trying to do this by applying this css class:

```
.applied-css {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width: 85px;
    height: 85px;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

And using this line of JS:

```
$(this).closest('table').find("col").eq($(this).index()).find(".div-default").addClass("applied-css");
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this working?

I should add that when I say "expand" the TH, I am basically faking the look of expanding. I use CSS to overlay a square on the TH that is larger than the TH square. This will slightly cut off the cells next to it, but I am OK with that. I can get that working when I hover the actual TH using `:hover` in CSS. But I want to get it working in jquery to apply it when I hover a cell on the table.

Comment: Maybe include the relevant HTML here as well?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't attempt to apply the `applied-css` class.  Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you specify exactly which part you're having trouble with?  Given what you've provided, seems like you could quite easily apply `.applied-css` to the correct place.  Is it the css or the jquery?  https://jsfiddle.net/ucpw0fxL/

Comment: Using jquery (similar to above), I am having problems targeting the row/col TD element that is highlighted, and then applying my CSS to the TH element that corresponds to it. I will make a couple more fiddles showing what I've tried.

Comment: `$(this).closest('table').find("tr:first").find("th").eq($(this).index())` (see my fiddle earlier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would do. In the th you want the content to expand I'd add a child layer containing the content I want to show like the following:

```
<div class="expand hidden">
    test 1
</div>
```

I would update your hover behaviour to this:

```
$("table").on('mouseover mousedown mouseleave','td', function(e) {
  if (e.type == 'mouseover' || e.type == 'mousedown') {
  $(this).parent().addClass("hover");
  $(this).closest('table').find("col").eq($(this).index()).addClass("hover");

  $(this).closest('table').find('thead > tr > th').eq($(this).index()).children(".expand").removeClass("hidden");
 } else {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("hover");
  $(this).closest('table').find('col').eq($(this).index()).removeClass("hover");

  $(this).closest('table').find('thead > tr > th').eq($(this).index()).children(".expand").addClass("hidden");
 }
});
```

What I do here is I remove the class 'hidden' on mouseover and add it on mouseout.

Last for the css:

```
th {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  position: relative;
}
.expand {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  height: 40px;
  transition: all 0.4s;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.hidden {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OP is looking to expand the relevant header for the column, not the cell itself, though it's very similar and just slightly different targeting.

Comment: This did it for me. Thank you so much for your response!